# CSS - Behaviour of a div with height and max-height

Tags: css, html

If you have a div:

```
<div id="test">
  <img src="http://..." />
</div>
```

With CSS:

```
#test {
  height: x;
  max-height: x + y;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Is it safe to assume that the div will always grow past its initial height of x and stop growing (and start scrolling) at x + y as the image with height x + y + z loads?

If not, how would I go about achieving this behaviour consistently across modern browsers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

no, you need to use min-height instead of height.

height will set a fixed height and the container will not grow or shrink.

min-height will set a minimum height and max-height a maximum height, the container will then grow and shrink between those 2 points and the overflow auto will apply when its greater than the max-height.